# How to unzip file to disk and save path to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, callback

I'm trying to create an app where a user can upload a zipped file, the app will unzip the file and save it to disk, and a path to the file will be saved to MongoDB for later retrieval.

I'm having a hard time getting the upload from form, unzipping, saving to disk, and uploading path of the unzipped file to the database all in one function. I'm really new to this and and am trying to learn about callbacks and such, I can't find any working solution for what I'm trying to do.

This is what my functions currently looks like:

```
// Multer is a form handling middleware
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file)
    cb(null, './uploads/unzip') 
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
  },
})
const upload = multer({ storage }).single('file'); //this is the 1st func in the route

const unzipp = async (req, res, next) => { //second func in route 
  try {
    const dir = 'uploads/unzipped/';      
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    stream.pipe(unzip.Extract({path: dir}))
      .on('entry', function () {
        var fileName = entry.path;
        var type = entry.type;
        var size = entry.size;
        console.log(fileName, type, size)
        if (type.isDirectory) {
           postfile()           //TRYING TO CALL POSTFILE() HERE
           console.log('unzipped and path saved')
        } else {
           res.error('Failed unzipping')
          }
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, function (e) {
        if (e) throw e;
        console.log('successfully deleted '+req.file.path);
    });
  })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
next();
}

//Upload is a mongoDB cluster Schema
async function postfile () {
  try{ 
  let newUpload = new Upload(req.body); //new instance of uplaod based on the model based on req.body
  newUpload.title = req.body.title;
  newUpload.description = req.body.description;
  newUpload.labels = req.body.labels;
  newUpload.filePath = fileName; //ASSIGN FILEPATH IN DB SCHEMA TO UNZIPPED FILE PATH
  console.log("filePath saved")
  newUpload.save()
    .then(newUpload => {
      res.status(200).json({file: "File added successfully"})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send('File upload failed to save to DB :(')
    })

  } catch (e) {

    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to call the function to save the mongo schema in unzipp function. This is the post route in a separate folder:

```
router.post('/upload', FileCtrl.upload, FileCtrl.unzipp)
```

- I've also tried saving the entry path of the unzipped file as a global var (fileName) and assigning the path in the Schema as fileName, but it doesn't work either:

```
const unzipp = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const dir = 'uploads/unzipped/';      
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    stream.pipe(unzip.Extract({path: dir}))
      .on('entry', function () {
        fileName = entry.path;
        type = entry.type;
        size = entry.size;
        console.log(fileName, type, size)
        // if (type.isDirectory) {
        //    console.log('unzipped and path saved')
        // } else {
        //    res.error('Failed unzipping')
        //   }
    result = {
        file: fileName,
        message:"File has been extracted"
    };
    //var file = req.file 

    fs.unlink(req.file.path, function (e) {
        if (e) throw e;
        console.log('successfully deleted '+req.file.path);
    });

    res.json(result);
  })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
  next();
}

const postfile = async (req, res) => {
  try{ 
  console.log("Posting to DB")
  let newUpload = new Upload(req.body); //new instance of uplaod based on the model based on req.body
  newUpload.title = req.body.title;
  newUpload.description = req.body.description;
  newUpload.labels = req.body.labels;
  newUpload.filePath = fileName;
  console.log("Ok so far")
  newUpload.save()
    .then(newUpload => {
      res.status(200).json({file: "File added successfully"})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send('File upload failed to save to DB :(')
    })

  } catch (e) {

    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

- this gives the error " ReferenceError: fileName is not defined "
- the new route looks like this:

```
router.post('/upload', FileCtrl.upload, FileCtrl.unzipp, FileCtrl.postfile)
```

I've been trying to solve this for a really long time and would really appreciate some advice.

EDIT: 
For testing purposes I hardcoded the filepath and it saved to the DB perfectly...

```
const postfile = async (req, res) => {
  try{ 
  console.log("Posting to DB")
  //var stream = fs.readdirSync('./uploads/unzipped/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2')
  let newUpload = new Upload(req.body); //new instance of uplaod based on the model based on req.body
  newUpload.title = req.body.title;
  newUpload.description = req.body.description;
  newUpload.labels = req.body.labels;
  newUpload.filePath = './uploads/unzipped/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2';
  console.log("Ok so far")
  newUpload.save()
    .then(newUpload => {
      res.status(200).json({file: "File added successfully"})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send('File upload failed to save to DB :(')
    })

  } catch (e) {

    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Obviously this isn't practical or dynamic, but it's possible.